# universal disabled property in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I'm finding it cumbersome to write short-circuited js conditionals to check for everything. I don't like the way it nests into the code and how its not readable most of the time like shown below:

```
{someCondition &&
    <someComponent />
}
```

Is there a way to use a disabled property in react to make code like shown below:

```
<someComponent disabled={!someCondition}/>
```

I think this looks more intuitive. Is there a way this disabled property can be implemented universally for all components in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that that syntax is a bit nasty and hard to read, but it's the price you pay for the React approach to templating as pure Javascript expressions. Your suggestion could be implemented via a higher-order component (HOC) or hook, using the property to set `display:none` or some such, but it has a major disadvantage: disabling will still mean that React will have to run the component logic, and will still appear in the React DOM tree, even if nothing ends up displayed. The syntax you dislike ensures that the component is completely ignored.

Comment: No I'm not just talking about display:none. I think this can be done through HOC, like `return !props.disabled ? (<component />`) : null`. Thanks for your response :).

Comment: Maybe `disabled` isn't the property name then. `omit`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a props disabled but in the child component the same conditionnal will be use...

You can make a cleaner syntax by using if in the render function
    Render(){
    If(condition)
        Return(...)
    Else
        Return(<...>)